# Refresh include with menu item not work

Tags: java, web, primefaces

I when I click on Login it does not refresh the include does anyone know what is the problem ?

I've tried other ways but continues to give error
Code

Index.xhtml

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Meu Sistema</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div align="center">
        <p:layout style="min-width:1020px;max-width:1020px;min-height:600px">
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:panelGroup id="include">
                    <ui:include src="#{Controlomenu.pagina}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </div>
<p:dock position="bottom">
    <p:menuitem value="Login" icon="imagens/lock.png" url="#" actionListener="#{Controlomenu.Paginalogin}" update=":include" />
    <p:menuitem value="Registar" icon="imagens/register.png" url="#" actionListener="#{Controlomenu.Paginaregistar}" update=":include"/>
</p:dock>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Controlomenu.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Controlomenu")
@SessionScoped
public class Controlomenu {
    @Autowired
    private String pagina;

public Controlomenu(){
    this.pagina= "hello.xhtml";
}
    public String getPagina() {
        return pagina;
    }

    public void setPagina(String pagina) {
        this.pagina = pagina;
    }
    public void Paginalogin() {
        setPagina("login.xhtml");   
    }
    public void Paginaregistar() {
        setPagina("registar.xhtml");    
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code see if it works

```
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Meu Sistema</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
<h:form id="outputForm">
        <div align="center">
            <p:layout style="min-width:1020px;max-width:1020px;min-height:600px">
                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <h:panelGroup id="include">
                        <ui:include src="#{Controlomenu.pagina}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </div>
</h:form>
<h:form id="dockForm">
    <p:dock position="bottom">
        <p:menuitem value="Login" icon="imagens/lock.png" url="#" actionListener="#{Controlomenu.Paginalogin}" update=":outputForm:include" />
        <p:menuitem value="Registar" icon="imagens/register.png" url="#" actionListener="#{Controlomenu.Paginaregistar}" update=":outputForm:include"/>
    </p:dock>
</h:form:>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some text/explanation to your answers... And 'answers' should not contain 'try to see if this works'.  It should work, or explicity state that it is kind of pseudo code, or manually hacked without running it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wrap your code after `<h:body>` in a `<h:form>` tag.

A form allows data to be sent to a server for processing.